# How to sum correlation, or, calculate correlation of disjointed variables

Tags: c#, windows, excel, math, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the correlation of 2 array of variables, but the array is disjointed in the middle - but I'm trying to obtain one correlation coefficient

Example;

```
x:1, 2, [disjointed], 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6

y:2, 4, [disjointed], 9.1, 9, 8.9, 8.8, 8.7, 8.6
```

**See the excel file I uploaded: http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=1UfQx3cUj**

because the disjoint in the middle, there is somewhat a jump in value and when I correlate the whole set of variable together I obtain a correlation coefficient that is not really reflective of the relationship between the variables

How would I be able to calculate one correlation coefficient? I can calculate two separate correlations but is there anyway to sum 2 correlation together?

Thank you Sirs

[Edit: formatting & also added link to excel file]

Comment: can you provide code which calculates it right now? what is "disjointed"?

Comment: Hi Ilya; i'm using excel's =correl to calculate, basically, I have 2 array sets (call it array1 and array2) and I'm trying to calculate the correlation of variables when array1 is declining, and also calculate the correlation when variables in array1 is increasing; because of this i get disjoints in the middle because array1 is increasing in the middle and i'm trying to calculate the correlation when array1 is decreasing. hope this helps, i will upload my excel numbers when i get home [edit:sentence]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: look at measures of dependence OTHER than correlation.

If I understand your question correctly, you are are thinking of a problem where the data look like this:

```
#R code
N=500
set.seed(10)
x = rnorm(N)
y = rnorm(N,10*x)
plot(x,y)
abline(reg = lm(y~x))
#correlation
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.9954706
```

[image]

These are obviously correlated X and Y variables.

However, your situation looks more like this (obviously, this is simplified to show a point):

```
abs = ifelse(x>0, 10, -10)
y2 = rnorm(N,abs*x)
plot(x,y2)
abline(reg = lm(y2~x))
cor(x,y2)
[1] -0.01952952
```

[image]

Correlation is a function of the linear relationship between two variables. In the top image, it's clear that Y depends heavily on X, and the correlation near 1 reflects the linear relationship. However, in the bottom image, even though Y depends heavily on X, the correlation coefficient is nearly 0 (and would be truly 0 in a very large sample).

This is just a shortcoming of correlation - there's no "fix" in which you could sum the correlation of X and Y above and below X=0. If you want better ways to characterize how your data are related, look into (for example) non-linear regression techniques. Better yet, work with a statistician at your institution (or find one nearby). There is no way to know exactly what you need without seeing more data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a correlation that summarizes the two sets, you can compute a meta-correlation by

1) Transforming your R and size into Fisher's Z and its standard error

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation

2) Integrating them via meta-analysis using for example

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmeta/index.html